# Why the object won't push into one array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

**Can someone help on how to push all object values into one array please?**

```
  const countryObject = data.countryBorders

      for ( var i = 0; i < countryObject.length; i++ ) {

        let countries = []
        let country = countryObject[i].properties.name

        countries.push(country)

        console.log(contries)
```

**it print**

```
["Bahamas"]["Canada"]["Costa Rica"]["Cuba"]...
```

**but I need it to print in one array under *countries* variable like**

```
["Bahamas", "Canada", "Costa Rica", "Cuba"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with where you are initializing the `countries` array. Since you have it in the `for-loop`, you are creating a new array for each iteration, resulting in the previous country to be lost.

You should initialize the `countries` variable before the `for-loop`, and then log it after the `for-loop`.

```
const countryObject = data.countryBorders;
const countries = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < countryObject.length; i++ ) {            
    let country = countryObject[i].properties.name;

    countries.push(country);
}

console.log(contries);
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be much simpler using `Array.map`

```
const countries = data.countryBorders.map(country => country.properties.name);
console.log(countries);
```

Comment: Hope you learnt something in the process @Coder_k